# Disable "Foxit Reader PDF" tab in Microsoft Office

Tags: microsoft-office, foxit-reader

How can I get rid of `Foxit Reader PDF` tab from Word / PowerPoint and other Office programs?

How can I do this permanently, because I have a strange feeling, that this is a recurring problem and it reappears after each Foxit Reader update.

Comment: Sure don't see that in my Office 2013 or 2010 suite.

Comment: @mdpc That's quite possible. I have Foxit Reader installed on both my computers and one of them have that tab installed, while another one does not have it. Foxit Company provides no details, neither about when Foxit PDF tabs are added to Office, nor how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can:

1. Run PowerPoint.
2. Select `File` > `PowerPoint options` > `Add-Ins`.
3. In opened tab (manager list) select `COM ADD-ins` from bottom drop-down list and click `Go`.
4. In opened popup select any existing copy of `Ppt Reader Addin` and click `Remove`.
5. Click `OK` to close all opened windows.

However, keep in mind, that yes -- this is a recurring problem. Above recipe for removing `Foxit Reader PDF` tab any of Office programs isn't permanent. It will work only until next update of main Foxit Reader. After that, it will re-appear again.

This is due to setting selected during installation of Foxit Reader (`Foxit Reader Creator` > `PPT Plugin`). And the only way to get rid of that tab permanently, is to uninstall Foxit Reader completely, then install it again, this time **not checking** `PPT Plugin` option (or related).

Answer (score 2):

I tried the tip, but it didn't work. It asked me to login as an administrator. In fact I am. What I did and it worked is to remove the plugins in the windows exlporer. Find where they are stored (C:/program files/foxit software/foxit reader/plugins/creator/x86) and remove them. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If necessary start Office program 'as Administrator':

1. Search `Excel`/`Word`/`Powerpoint`/etc in the *Windows Start Menu*,
2. don't start but ***right-click*** and select `run as Administrator` (german: `Als Adminstrator starten`).
3. Then try again with `File` > `Options` > `Add-Ins` ... `COM ADD-ins` etc... as described above.